# HTML/jQuery - Preventing empty text nodes

Tags: jquery, html, textnode

I'm trying to prevent the creation of empty text nodes whenever I add

- newlines,
- spaces (including non-breaking spaces)
- tabs

to my HTML structure.

Eg.

```
<div><div>    <!-- Node not created -->
<div>
                <!-- Node created -->
<div>
```

Eg1.

```
<div><div>    <!-- Node not created -->
<div> <div>     <!-- Node created -->
```

Eg2.

```
<div><div>    <!-- Node not created -->
<div>            <!-- Node created -->
    <div>
                 <!-- Node created -->
    </div>    
<div>            <!-- Node created -->
```

Here, for a better undestading:
see what happens into the first `<DIV>`s - 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNjCW/14/)

Comment: is there a particular reason to do this

Comment: Why ? Just because you're worried there are some empty text nodes in the browser's memory ?

Comment: it helps with inline block elements

Comment: Well the final goal is to replace the non empty text nodes with other content... So I'm looking the DOM for all the text nodes, but my function replaces the text in all of them. Inlcuding the empty ones.

Comment: How will you create these nodes? Will they be created in jQuery using some sort of Form input?

Comment: Text nodes are created automatically :(

Comment: did you write the markup?

Comment: I've updated my question, have a check at the code!

Answer (score 3):

Every time you manipulate the DOM, call `node.normalize()` to the parent node, it will do the job.

See more at [Node.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.normalize)

**UPDATED**

According to the fiddle you provide, I take a deep look into this issue, I run following code in Chrome 29, based on your html structure.

```
var i = 0;
function traverse(node){
    if (node.firstChild) {
        traverse(node.firstChild);
    }

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        console.log("text node " + ++i + ": " + node.nodeValue);
        if (node.nodeValue !== '') {
            console.log("text node " + i + " is not null");
        }
        if (node.nodeValue.match(/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/g)) {
            console.log("nonsense node");
        }
    }

    if (node.nextSibling) {
        traverse(node.nextSibling);
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doTraverse);

function doTraverse(){
    traverse(document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[0]);
}
```

and get these results:

```
text node 1: 

text node 1 is not null
nonsense node
text node 2: 

text node 2 is not null 
nonsense node 
text node 3: 

text node 3 is not null 
nonsense node 
text node 4: 

text node 4 is not null 
nonsense node 
text node 5: 
            text

text node 5 is not null 
text node 6: a paragraph 
text node 6 is not null
text node 7: 

text node 7 is not null 
nonsense node 
text node 8: a paragraph 
text node 8 is not null 
text node 9: a paragraph 
text node 9 is not null 
text node 10: 
             more text

text node 10 is not null 
text node 11: 


text node 11 is not null 
nonsense node
```

to our surprise, there are way more `empty` text node than we expect. However, if we inspect these elements in Chrome's inspector, everything seems working fine. I guess Chrome optimizes this issue in rendering engine but not in DOM.

We have a clear idea that those `empty` text nodes actually contains `linebreak`s, which makes your code doesn't work as you expect. So if you do want to remove those text nodes, you can traverse the DOM , find them and remove them(which will be very inefficient and I appreciate better solution).

BTW, in this scenario, `node.normalize()` won't work for you since it just remove real empty text node.

Comment: So in my example where should I add this command ??
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNjCW/14/)

Comment: I fail to see any empty `text node` in your fiddle

Comment: Inbetween the first divs there are those odd nodes!!

Comment: How to delete nonsense text nodes? Normalize doesn't remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Add comments if you think it nessesary

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

This will make the white space commented out and not insert a text node

from http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

eg 1

```
<div><div><!-- 
--><div><!--

--><div>
```

eg 2

```
<div><div><!--
--><div><!-- --><div>
```

eg 3

```
<div><div><!--
--><div><!--
    --><div><!--

    --></div><!--    
--><div>
```

Makes your markup fairly ugly but removes the text nodes

Comment: I can't see one case where adding these markups to have comment nodes instead of empty text nodes would be useful.

Comment: When you need to put two `display: inline-block;` elements next to each other and dont want there to be a gap in between the elements not generated by padding or margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple cleaning function on your DOM:

```
function cleanNode(node) {
 var child;
 for (var i = node.childNodes.length; i--;) {
  child = node.childNodes[i];
  // If commentt/textNode and has no non-whitespace character in it, delete it.
  if (child.nodeType === 3 || child.nodeType === 8 && !/\S/.test(child.nodeValue)) {
   node.removeChild(child);
   n--;
  }
  else {
   cleanNode(child);
  } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NodeIterator` to remove the blank text nodes:
(this code works in browsers from ~2015+)

```js
function cleanup() {
    document.createNodeIterator(
        document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        {acceptNode(node) {
            if (node.data.trim()=="") node.remove()
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
        }}
    ).nextNode()
}
```

(Note: normally you would call `.nextNode()` in a loop, but by returning REJECT from the acceptNode function, you only have to call it once)

You should call `cleanup()` as soon as possible after the html is parsed.
ex: using `<script defer>`, or a `<script>` at the end of the document.
Or, if that isn't possible:

```
if (document.readyState=='loading')
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cleanup)
else
    cleanup()
```